# Home Studio Echo Problem

Tags: sound-design, sound, home-studio, echo

I've got a room 5x4x2,5 m set up for a Home Studio.

Before it was a much larger room that I made smaller by using plasterboard with insulating material. 
Now in the room I've got some forniture on the sides: 
- small wardrobe 
- a 3-sits-couch 
- 2 chests of drawers 
- a drum set on a carpet

Now even if the sides are almost covered, the room suffers a big echo when I play the drums or listen to music or even if I talk loud.

Have you got any suggestion on how to improve the sound quality in the room?

Comment: Your real 'fix' was at the point you built the new walls. Making no two opposing surfaces parallel, all dimensions as non-relational distances & resonant surfaces in differing construction materials would have done a lot to aid your current dilemma. You are now stuck with a sub-standard post-fix which will never be as good as if you'd asked this question before building [which is why I can't post this as an answer] - upvotes to the two existing answers, though ;)

Comment: On a very cheap practical solution, though - opening wardrobe doors & drawers can provide 'happy accident' frequency-trapping. Experiment with opening sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, if you have a hard floor like cement or wood or tile...get an area carpet.

Otherwise, you need to use absorber panels.

Generally acoustic studio treatment requires 3 devices....bass traps, absorbers, and diffusors (heads up, you won't need all of them).

Bass traps, trap bass in the corners of rooms to prevent standing waves (spikes in bass volume).

Absorbers simply absorb sound, especially the higher frequency, to prevent reflections and echos.

Diffusors diffuse sound. This prevents abnormalities and phasing issues with reflections, while not killing them totally (like absorbers do).

I recommend you research all of them, to see what you want.

BUT, long story short, if you just want to kill the echo, all you are going to need is absorbers. If you want to do highly critical listening, like mixing and master with studio monitors....then you are going to want to spend the extra time for diffusers and bass traps.

The wonderful thing about sound absorbers is that they can be made quite easily, cheaply, and be custom styled to even improve the room aesthetics.

Generally they are 2x4' panels. You make the frame out of wood, like 2x2 spruce, then you put a single bat of home insulation in the frame, then wrap in with the fabric of your choice. You can find lots of tutorials online...but as long as you have insulation in fabric hanging on your walls, you are good to go.

You won't have to cover the entire wall, maybe 25-30% of the surface will help.

Here is a tutorial, but I encourage you to investigate all sorts of designs.

http://acousticsfreq.com/how-to-build-your-own-acoustic-panels/

Answer (score 2):

All hard parallel surfaces are your enemy. Since the space has already been built out you can't (I'm assuming) easily make the walls non-parallel. So you're really left with applying treatments.

Some form of sound absorbers would be the most logical first step. Depending on the floor material (and what you can or willing) do with that) you may also need some absorbers on the ceiling. And with drums you will almost certainly want some bass traps in the corners. If you're going to be mixing & mastering in this space, at a minimum you'll probably want some form of diffuser on the back wall as well.